# Heroku/Auth0 Android + JAVA API Error

Tags: java, javascript, android, auth0

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-java/tree/master/examples/java-api

The link displays the Auth0 + Java API Seed github.  After connecting with the given command it states "You can then try to do a GET to http://localhost:3001/secured/ping which will throw an error if you don't send the JWT in the header."  I'm recieving this error and i'm not sure how accomplish sending a JWT in a header.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the JWT in the Authorization header. For example:

```
GET /secured/ping HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3001
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJI...
```